# Android/Firebase - How to add retrieved data to an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having some issues trying to do this because the data is loaded async.

I have an recyclerView and I need to push the data into a list so it can be recycled displaying the infos on the screen, but it turns out to be kinda hard to do this.

That's what I got until now:

```
refQuestions.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Question question = dataSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
                arrayList.add(question.title);
                Log.d("MyApp", question.title);
            }
```

I want the code to kinda "stops" here and only continue to executes after the data has been completely loaded into my array, like some kind of callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addChildEventListener` or you can use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, as in my code below:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Question question = ds.getValue(Question.class);
            arrayList.add(question.title);
        }

        //Do what you need to do with your arrayList
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
refQuestions.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

As you can see, a quick solve for this problem is to use the `arrayList` only inside the `onDataChange()` method. If you want to use it outside, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you! I checked out the other post you mentioned, exactly what I needed! Amazing!!! Tks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onDataChange method to add the fetched result to the arraylist

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Question question = ds.getValue(Question.class);
        arrayList.add(question.title);
    }
}
});
```

And then you can easily display them in the recycler view. For more info [click here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)

Comment: Your answer is for Cloud Firestore and the OP is asking for a solution regarding Firebase real-time database, which is a different product.

Comment: Sorry for that, I totally missed that. Checkout my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getQuestions() {
    DatabaseReference refQuestions = /* initialise the reference here */;
    refQuestions.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                /* keep iterating through all the children, this way you can
                   keep track of the retrieval progress */
                for (DataSnapshot question : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    arrayList.add(question.getValue(Question.class).title);
                }
                /* this is where you write the code what to do after getting
                   all data or call another function to do the job*/
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

You can also replace this..

```
refQuestions.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

with

```
refQuestions.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

for real-time update